# cURL returns binary data instead of html

Tags: php, ssl, curl, https

```
function curl($url) {

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/25.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'long cookie here');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;

}
```

The original url I'm feeding it is http://example.com/i-123.html but if I open in browser, I get redirected to https://example.com/item-description-123.html (so I added `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`).

However, the output of this function is binary data.

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0003 ed7d e976 db38
f2ef e7f8 2930 9ac9 d86e 9b92 b868 f3a2
3e5e 9374 67fb c7ee 74f7 e4e6 f880 2428
31a6 4835 172f 3dd3 8f74 3fde 17b8 f7c5
6e15 008a 8ba8 2db1 3ce9 25a7 dba4 4810
......
```

How do I fix this? I tried adding

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

(copied from somewhere). Didn't work.

`file_get_contents()` gives me the same output.

Comment: how do you print the output? How did you get that columns data on your screen?

Comment: via terminal
`$ php parser.php > output`

Comment: if a php echoes the binary data, it is just displayed as broken characters. I don't get it how you get those columns on your screen

Comment: Well, the command written above doesn't `echo` the output in the terminal, but saves it into a file. when you open the file with a text editor, you see what I posted.

Comment: try switching your text editor to UTF-8 text mode instead of binary

Comment: When I open with UTF-8 encoding http://i.stack.imgur.com/35D9F.png

Comment: Do you have `openssl` proprly installed? Maybe it's broken or something and you're getting real SSL data?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Will give it a try later and post the result here.

Comment: Well, `openssl` is the latest version... I just tried `wget`-ing another website over HTTPS and it worked perfect. Question is still how to get this one to work and what's bothering me more - what's causing this? :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, the solution was pathetic...

Using `wget -S http://example.com` I found out that the content is compressed (gzipped). Using `gunzip` I successfully extracted the html.

Also added to my original PHP script

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
```

And it worked like a charm.

Comment: Very interesting. A thing to remember. Glad you found the answer!

Comment: Wow. I thought the site was using some sort of trickery to return garbage and prevent me from scraping it. Thanks!

Comment: Or add the --compressed option for auto ungzip.

Comment: As a side note - I was running curl from the CLI. Adding `--compressed` as an option, mean't it then correctly downloaded as HTML. This answer pushed me in the right direction :)

Comment: This also worked for me, In windows I piped to `download.gzip` and then extracted it with `7zip`.