# Curl result is encoded

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing a POST request in PHP using cURL.

The request is working well but once I save the result into a file I'm getting this result instead of HTML code on httpfox:

```
1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0003 6d50 3d4f c330
10dd fd2b 8eee 8913 8484 842c 0f34 a9a8
5468 8730 30a6 f141 2cb9 7670 2e15 f9f7
9c93 a548 78f0 e9ee 7df8 9dd5 5d75 dc36
1fa7 1a5e 9ad7 039c de9f 0ffb 2d6c 3229
f775 b393 b26a aa15 b9cf 0b29 ebb7 8d16
aaa7 8bd3 aac7 d670 4396 1cea 87f2 11ea
9f01 3b6a c906 0fbb d63a 344a aea8 5072
61ab 7330 7332 28f5 7f64 1e0b 35e8 a647
c01b f8cb 5ed1 83f5 400c ac3a 88f8 3de1
4859 b2c5 283e 2d3a 035d 98f8 f681 e08c
7041 2e33 6bec 0823 c62b c65c 24e7 ce59
f4c4 234f 6a88 9c0d f8ac ae4f 5016 45d6
054f d64f c8a1 179c 8be6 5447 efe6 25c1
2de7 4fce f4d0 340c 2112 9a3c a958 ba2c
cc9b a51f 13bf 9604 6e11 6c01 0000
```

Can anyone explain me what kind of code it is and how can I get the HTML result from the cURL response?

Comment: See this thread, it looks like its Binary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283822/curl-returns-binary-data-instead-of-html

Comment: @blamb I have already enabled gzip , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING , "",
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => COOKIE_FILE,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => COOKIE_FILE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this

it seems that the request ha not been done

as I had read the binary file with this code

```
<?php
$lines = gzfile('2.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
?>
```

and it says Expectation Failed

so I have set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to `array('Expect:')`